# Set of XOR constraints

Tags: linear-programming, constraints, constraint-programming

I have a formulation of linear inequality constraints (A1, ..., An) from which I need *exactly* one to be true:

> A1 xor A2 xor ... xor An

and I'd like to transform the above into a typical and-related set of constraints (B1, ..., Bm)

> B1 and B2 and ... and Bm

in order to provide it as input to a linear programming solver.

How can I perform this transformation, or at least find a feasible solution to a set of xor-related constraints?

Comment: I hope you mean an *integer* programming solver, because of course this is not convex and cannot be linearized.

Answer (score 1):

Note that the set where a condition of the type $B_1 \text{ and } B_2 \text{ and } \ldots \text{ and } B_m$ is true, is always a convex polyhedron. This is not the case for $\oplus$-related constraints, the set where these are true is in general not even convex (Think of $(x_1 \ge 0) \oplus (x_2 \ge 0)$). What you can do is, solve the $n$ problems with constraints (1) $B_1 \text{ and } \neg B_2 \text{ and } \cdots \text{ and } \neg B_n$, (2) $\neg B_1 \text { and } B_2 \text{ and } \cdots \text{ and } \neg B_n$, $\ldots$ ($n$) $\neg B_1 \text{ and } \neg B_2 \text{ and } \cdots \text{ and } B_n$ seperately.